# How to deserialize JSON to two differnet classes according to object type?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to read a JSON file with this format:

```
{
    "A":
    {
        "type": "option_a",
        "state": 0,
    },
    
    "B":
    {
        "type": "option_b",
        "state": 1,
    },
    
    "C":
    {
        "type": "option_a",
        "state": 0,
    },
    
    .
    .
    .
    
    "Z":
    {
        "MODE A":
        {
            "status a": 0,
            "status b": 0,
        },
        "MODE B":
        {
            "status a": 0,
            "status b": 1,
        },
        "MODE C":
        {
            "status a": 1,
            "status b": 0,
        },
}
```

As I see it that the correspending classes should be:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public int State {get; set;}
}

// for handeling the 'Z' structure:
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassBInternalStructure Mode {get; set;}
}

public class ClassBInternalStructure
{
    public int StatusA {get; set;}
    public int StatusB {get; set;}
```

I've searched a lot of simialer questions, none with the exact sloution for this case,
as far as I managed to find.

If I understand correctly the right approach to such a task is to used the Newtonsoft JsonConvert.
Here Is what I've broght up till now (C# 8), I would be grateful for any help to fill the missing  content (hopefully i'm in the correct direction):

```
public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
 {

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                //????
            }
            else if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
            {
                //????
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("...");
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Another part which I didn't manage to figure is how to invoke this method -

```
public class JsonParser
{
        public void Parsing(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                using StreamReader sr = new(filePath);
                string JsonData = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                // is another 'MyJsonConverter' override class needed?

                ???.ReadJson(????, null, null, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advnace!

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON format?

Comment: Yes, I contains details which aren't supposed to change - to change the format can be a sloution.
But I don't want to seperate totally the data to two different files, since I might reuse this pattern in simialr tasks later and they do come from the same source.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` supports this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: In my opinion it's not a good idea to deserialize into derived types, because it ties the JSON data (a universal format) to the deserializer that you are using. Other clients (maybe not even dotnet ones) reading the same JSON will have to jump through the same hoops.

Comment: @AmitaiWeil It can be converted to your classes without any problem , only I don't understand what are you going to gain in this case. It will be the same if you just parse your json string. What is the pourpose of "Z"? Now many items  of this kind you have. You question certainly needs more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

correct classes

```
public partial class test
{

    public A A { get; set; }


    public A B { get; set; }


    public A C { get; set; }


    public Dictionary<string, Z> Z { get; set; }
}

public partial class A
{

    public string Type { get; set; }


    public string State { get; set; }
}

public partial class Z
{

    public string StatusA { get; set; }


    public string StatusB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide some explanation as well